# Conversion operators in class templates

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

I have two class templates `TemplateA<T>` and `TemplateB<T>`. Now, I want to define a conversion operator in `TemplateB<T>` in order to allow implicit type conversions from `TemplateB<T>` to `TemplateA<T>`. However, the following code produces a compilation error:

```
struct ClassA {};

template<typename T>
struct TemplateA {
  T val;
};

template<typename T>
struct TemplateB {
  T val;

  template<typename ValT>
  operator TemplateA() const {
    TemplateA<ValT> a;
    a.val = val;
    return a;
  }
};

int main() {
  TemplateB<ClassA> b;
  TemplateA<ClassA> a = b;
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:13:12: error: expected type-specifier before 'TemplateA'
   operator TemplateA() const {
            ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to define a conversion operator in `TemplateB<T>` to allow implicit type conversions from `TemplateB<T>` to `TemplateA<T>`

That doesn't require a conversion function template. A plain conversion function will do:

```
operator TemplateA<T>() const {
    TemplateA<T> a;
    a.val = val;
    return a;
}
```

You need a template only if you want to allow conversion from `TemplateB<Foo>` to `TemplateA<Bar>`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279183/2069064), you could also define the conversion the other way if you so choose - instead of adding a [non-template] conversion function to `TemplateB` you can add a [non-template] converting constructor to `TemplateA`:

```
template<typename T>
struct TemplateB {
    T val;
};

template<typename T>
struct TemplateA {
    T val;

    TemplateA() = default;

    // converting constructor
    TemplateA(TemplateB<T> const& t)
    : val(t.val)
    { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A template parameter forms part of the type definition, so you cannot omit it in your conversion operator:

```
template<typename ValT>
  operator TemplateA<ValT>() const {
    TemplateA<ValT> a;
    a.val = val;
    return a;
  }
```

It helps to think that the compiler will append templated type to the computed type of a template. So your code will generate something like `operator TemplateA_ClassA() const` which will be used to convert `TemplateB_ClassA` to `TemplateA_ClassA`.